# Drools java.lang.NullPointerException at org.drools.reteoo.RuleTerminalNode any idea

Tags: jboss, drools, rule-engine

As usual in these days I am working hard on drools. Honestly I have a lot of difficulties and I am a little bi discouraged. Now I have this problem.
My application has to monitor when a magnetic contact is activated and when it is contact released event has to be retracted. And viceversa. Here is my rule and the big null pointer I have. Any helps will be very appreciated! Thank you a lot!!

```
 rule "contact activated vs contact released"   salience 0 no-loop true
    when
        $contact_activated : Event(type == EventType.CONTACT_ACTIVATED) ||  

    $contact_released : Event(type == EventType.CONTACT_RELEASED)
        then

             if($contact_activated!= null) {
                retract($contact_activated);
             } else {
                retract($contact_released);
             }
end
```

and 
 I have

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.drools.reteoo.RuleTerminalNode$SortDeclarations.compare(RuleTerminalNode.java:477)
    at org.drools.reteoo.RuleTerminalNode$SortDeclarations.compare(RuleTerminalNode.java:473)
    at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1270)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1210)
    at org.drools.reteoo.RuleTerminalNode.<init>(RuleTerminalNode.java:119)
    at org.drools.RuleActivationListenerFactory.createActivationListener(RuleActivationListenerFactory.java:21)
    at org.drools.reteoo.builder.ReteooRuleBuilder.addSubRule(ReteooRuleBuilder.java:157)
    at org.drools.reteoo.builder.ReteooRuleBuilder.addRule(ReteooRuleBuilder.java:123)
    at org.drools.reteoo.ReteooBuilder.addRule(ReteooBuilder.java:110)
    at org.drools.reteoo.ReteooRuleBase.addRule(ReteooRuleBase.java:441)
    at org.drools.common.AbstractRuleBase.addRule(AbstractRuleBase.java:821)
    at org.drools.common.AbstractRuleBase.addPackages(AbstractRuleBase.java:555)
    at org.drools.reteoo.ReteooRuleBase.addPackages(ReteooRuleBase.java:458)
    at org.drools.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.addKnowledgePackages(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:150)
    at it.ipiu.pch.sel.RuleTest.before(RuleTest.java:1272)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug, I suggest you submit a JIRA to the project. Which version are you using?

At the same time, your rule is more complicated than it should. Every time you see an "if" in the consequence, it is a red flag something is not good. You can rewrite your rule as:

```
rule "contact activated vs contact released"
when
    $contact : Event( type in ( EventType.CONTACT_ACTIVATED, EventType.CONTACT_RELEASED ) )
then
    retract($contact);
end
```

Comment: Thank you I will do. A question in this way contact will be retracted also in case of both contact types are present? What if I want a xor like behaviour? in other hand I need to retract releasing contact fact when an activation is inserted and viceversa. Your rule works in this way? Thank you again.

Comment: I faced with the same problem. I'm using version 6.0.1.Final.